# How authenthic is "Usulal Qiraat" or "shatibiyyah " by Imam Shatibi

Tags: history

Recently online I encountered this book, people quote this specific passage:

25. "Now, the holder of the noble secret concerning sweet scents, he is
    Nāfi˘ who chose Medinah as (his) abode ":

"Some have mentioned this esteemed secret concerning the sweet
smell; when Nāfi˘ recited Qur`ān, the sweet smell of musk emanated from
his mouth. When he was asked concerning it he replied that he saw the
Prophet in a dream. He read to the Prophet, who blew into his mouth.
Since that time this sweet aroma started coming from his mouth",

I know Imam Shatibi (ra) is a respected scholar, but Has anyone ever encountered this work, can it be trusted?

Comment: Shatibiyyah is *the* work Imam Shatibi is known for. It gathers the different qiraat into one poem. But, Idk the authenticity of this narration about Nafi.

Comment: It is the basis for thr majority of qaari's around the world no matter if they excel one or more qira'a. The story of Nafi' is well known and mentioned in all biographical works. The story of abu Ja'afar the first imam in Medina from the time of Tabiyin on and one of the 10 qurra' is even more mysterious...